# How to uninstall Windows Powershell v1.0 on Windows 7 RTM

Tags: powershell

I noted recently that Windows Powershell v1.0 is installed on Windows 7 RTM, so I need to install Powershell v2.0 CTP 3 but I can't find it on "Uninstall Programs" and also tried on "Turn on/off Windows Features", How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just installing v2.0? Stupid question I know, but it might just install on top of v1.0 or uninstall it first.

Comment: Great question. I also was fooled by the stupid folder name, and because I assumed 2.0 would have intellisense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Althouth the folder is the same, it is Powershell v2 you have on your Win7. You can confirm this by running this command from inside powershell:
$PSVersionTable

on my (win7) workstation it reads:

```
> CLRVersion                    
> 2.0.50727.4927                                                                           BuildVersion                  
> 6.1.7600.16385                                                                           PSVersion                      2.0    
> WSManStackVersion              2.0    
> PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0,
> 2.0}                                                                               SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
> PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Where "PSVersion" is the giveaway :-)

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 ships with PowerShell 2.0; why do you think it's running 1.0?

See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd367858(WS.10).aspx.

> Windows® 7 includes Windows PowerShell 2.0.

Comment: I dont have the get-diagpack cmdlet used on PDC2008 with Powershell v2

Comment: and also I found a folder with v1.0 : "C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0"

Comment: It's 2.0. Have a look at the link.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Win7, but in XP you had to check the Show Updates checkbox in Add/Remove programs and in Vista you have to click the Show Installed Updates link in Programs and Features to see Powershell and be able to uninstall it.

Comment: I tryed that, the update packs are not equals, Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

As already indicated, Windows 7 comes with PowerShell v2.  Yes, it can *appear* that this is v1 because of the folder mentioned here and that scripts are "ps1", but trust me, it is v2.

Now, your comment about get-diagpack...  Don't solely base yourself on content from Fall 2008 (@ PDC).  Things could have changed several times since then.

If you want to check out the new diagnostics:
PS>cd $pshome\modules
PS>import-module .\PSDiagnostics
PS>get-command -pssnapin psdiagnostics

I've not checked, but you likely won't see anything allowing you to uninstall PowerShell.  It is basically considered part of the core OS now.  Just like you can't (still) remove command.exe....